# how to change button background when all edittext is filled

Tags: android, button, background, android-edittext

My app has seven editTexts and one button below them. I want the button to change its background when the user filled all editText with numeric values (int or double, except zero).

I think I should use OnTouchChangeListener but I am not sure how to do it, any advice?

Comment: did you try `textchangelistener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `addTextChangedListener` to your EditText.

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Add your logic here
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

// Remember to remove when whatever actions required have completed.
editText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Assuming all your EditText views require the same logic, create a single TextWatcher object and bind the listener to each as above. You can also implement this in your class:

```
class MyClass implements TextWatcher
```

And add the override methods into the class and write the code in the `onTextChanged()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Put a line inside your

```
 android:digits="123456789"
```

And in java file check for the length of edittext.if the length of all editext is greater than 1 then change the color of the button.
If worked ...check my answer